# Android override all textview Typeface in root view childs

Tags: android

i'm trying to override all `TextView`s in root `FrameLayout` by below code, but my solution doesn't work correctly:

My java code:

```
public static void overrideFonts(final Context context, final View v) {
    try {
        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
            for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = vg.getChildAt(i);
                overrideFonts(context, child);
            }
        } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/IRAN-Sans-Bold.ttf"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR Override fonts", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

set Typeface in `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Utils.overrideFonts(context, root_view);
}
```

layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/root_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ededed"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Guardanis no i dont get any error

Comment: @Guardanis i'm very sorry sir. i get error, post updated

Comment: @Guardanis error fixed now, but TypeFace could not set to textviews

Answer (score 0):

change root_view with this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Utils.overrideFonts(context, getWindow().getDecorView());
}
```